# Scrapy with Selenium does not detect HTML element loaded dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with Selenium to scrape content from this page: https://nikmikk.itch.io/door-knocker

In it, there is a table under the div with class `.game_info_panel_widget`, where the first row `Published   62 days ago` seems to be loaded dynamically.

I have try fetching the page as Scrapy sees but cannot find that row in the html.

```
scrapy fetch --nolog https://nikmikk.itch.io/door-knocker > test.html
```

Here is what I see in `test.html`, the first table row is the Status, not the Published row like when I view page source directly in Chrome.

```
<div class="game_info_panel_widget">                                                                                                                                         
    <table>                                                                                                                                              
        <tbody>                                                                                                                                                  
           <tr>                                                                                                                                                      
               <td>Status</td>                                                                                                                                                       
               <td>Prototype</td>                                                                                                                                                            
               ...                                                                                                                                               

           </tr>
            ...
```

In my class `SpiderDownloaderMiddleware`, I have included **Selenium**:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

class SpiderDownloaderMiddleware(object):
# Omitted other codes
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver.get(request.url)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".game_info_panel_widget"))
        )

        body = driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8-sig', request=request)
```

How do I check how that row is loaded and how I can scrape those infos?

**Updated**:
I followed @Yosuva A 's answer below and got something like this:

```
 9 days ago

In development
Platforms
Windows
Rating
(9)
Author
David Clark
Genre
Survival, Puzzle
Tags
3D, Creepy, First-Person, Horror, Psychological Horror, Short, Singleplayer, Spooky, Unity
Average session
A few seconds
Languages
English
```

But the output is inconsistent, sometimes it gives the desired one, sometimes it doesn't. I guess because Selenium waits for the general `td` element, which is common:

```
"//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']//table//tr//td"
```

I have tried to modified to use `td[@text='Published']` but Selenium gives timeout.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://thehive.itch.io/promnesia");
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='toggle_info_btn']").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']//table//tr//td"))) #Wait for specific element 

table_rows= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']//table//tr//td")

for rows in table_rows:
    print(rows.text)

driver.quit()
```

Any other way?

**Conclusion**:
It works if we `time.sleep(2)` after `click()` as suggested by Yosuva A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know whether this help or not

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://thehive.itch.io/promnesia");
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='toggle_info_btn']").click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']/table//tr//td"))) #Wait for specific element 

table_rows= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']/table//tr//td")

for rows in table_rows:
    print rows.text

driver.quit()
```

### Output

```
Updated
1 day ago
Published
9 days ago
Status
In development
Platforms
Windows
Rating
(9)
Author
David Clark
Genre
Survival, Puzzle
Tags
3D, Creepy, First-Person, Horror, Psychological Horror, Short, Singleplayer, Spooky, Unity
Average session
A few seconds
Languages
English
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, I am having a problem with the first field in the site: `Published  63 days ago` because it seems to be loaded later.  In your output, I don't see it being printed out.

Comment: How long it takes to load the published field?

Comment: @hydradon can you please add a screenshot with published field. i tried it in chrome and firefox , but i couldn't published field in any of the browser.

Comment: @hydradon This code will print all the details of ```game_info_panel_widget``` . Please give a try. I just updated my code with url which is having published field and it is returning all the fields including published field.

Comment: I followed your reply, but the output is inconsistent. Please see my update in the main question. In summary, sometimes it gives the correct output, sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @hydradon Can you please copy paste your full code here? so that i can check whether it is inconsistent

Comment: I have updated my question with the same code as yours

Comment: My code will try to extract all the values from the 'More information' section. I noticed  that some of your page doesn't have publish field in it.That is the reason you are not getting 'Published' values always. If the page actually has 'published' field inside more information section, then my code will extract it for sure.For an example ```https://thehive.itch.io/promnesia``` has published field in it whereas ```https://nikmikk.itch.io/door-knocker ``` page doesn't have published field.Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200524/discussion-between-yosuva-a-and-hydradon).