# Selenium + chromedriver is not able to load HTML in only some pages, but not other

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

This is in the same project I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260257/scrapy-with-selenium-does-not-detect-html-element-loaded-dynamically/58261275?noredirect=1#comment102917959_58261275)

However, this time I encounter another issue. Bascially, I am trying to get the 2 fields `Updated` and `Published` under the `More information` toggle link (the HTML to select for this toggle is `"//a[@class='toggle_info_btn']"`

In one page https://thehive.itch.io/promnesia, I am able to retrieve the 2 fields. But in another page https://dmullinsgames.itch.io/paper-jekyll, I cannot eventhough both have the same HTML.

Here is my code (as suggested by Yosuva A in the previous question):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://dmullinsgames.itch.io/paper-jekyll");
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='toggle_info_btn']").click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']/table//tr//td"))) #Wait for specific element 

table_rows= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='game_info_panel_widget']/table//tr//td")

for rows in table_rows:
    print(rows.text)

driver.quit()
```

When running this, I see *chromedriver* opens a Chrome windows with the page, but I don't see the 2 fields `Updated` and `Published` there. 
Here is what chromedriver sees when it opens an instance of Chrome:
[image]

Here is what **actually** there:
[image]
Please let me know what issue this is...

Comment: On the second page there are no fields `updated` and `published`. So how do you want to get them?

Comment: Hi @D.Weltrowski, yes there are... I am opening it in my browser, and I can see them under `More information` (But you need to click on the toggle). Just to confirm, the game is `paper-jekyll` Could you check again? Updated with screenshots

Comment: So the answer is quite simple here. You do not see Updated and Published on the second website until You are logged in. Which means You need to log in with selenium before You download the data.

Comment: But that does not explain why chromedriver can see those 2 fields in the first link `https://thehive.itch.io/promnesia`, without logging in

Comment: Well apparently the first one does not require loggin in to see those fields. And that is all to it. Since I saw the field in the first one as a guest.

Comment: @D.Weltrowski hey, thanks for the troubleshooting. If you post that as answer, i'll mark it as correct. However, now I have trouble with Scrapy login, have posted another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360351/scrapy-does-not-perform-log-in-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by D.Weltrowski in the comment, some fields in the page are only visible if logged in. Furthermore, the same field can be visible on one page but invisible on another. Therefore, the solution is to have Scrapy logged in before crawling and it will be able to scrape those data. Information on authenticated crawl [here](https://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-formrequest-logging-in/)